# Duda subconsulta en un INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Tengo una duda no logro comprender el siguiente ejercicio que estoy practicando de SQL

```
SELECT A.Nombre, A.Fabricante,A.Precio, F.Nombre FROM ARTICULOS A
INNER JOIN FABRICANTES F ON F.Codigo = A.Fabricante
AND A.Precio=(
    SELECT MAX(A.Precio) FROM ARTICULOS A
    WHERE A.Fabricante = F.Codigo
)
```

Lo que realiza es que muestra los campos (**Nombre**, **Fabricante** y **Precio**) con un **INNER JOIN** de **Artículos** y **Fabricantes**. Hasta allí comprendo correctamente, después de unir con los campos del primer `F.Codigo = A`.**Fabricante** hace otra validación para mostrar el Precio mayor de cada Fabricante, pero no logro comprender como funciona el último **WHERE**.

Selecciona el **Precio MAX** de Artículos donde el campo **A.Fabricante** es igual a **F.Codigo** y esto obtiene el valor del campo Precio máximo de cada Fabricante, pero no comprendo como lo realiza.

¿Compara cada campo de Artículos.Fabricante con cada campo de Fabricantes.Codigo? o ¿Como funciona este último **WHERE**?

Comment: ¿puedes pasar la sql de creación de esa base de datos (con  unas pocas filas)?

Comment: No le veo sentido a eso, puedes obtener el dato haciendo algo así: `SELECT A.Nombre, A.Fabricante,MAX(A.Precio) AS Precio, F.Nombre FROM ARTICULOS A
INNER JOIN FABRICANTES F ON F.Codigo = A.Fabricante`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es una subconsulta correlativa. Depende del motor, es lo que se conoce como el operador APPLY. Con esto se consigue que el máximo precio por articulo no sea 1 solo valor, sino 1 por fabricante.

```
CREATE TABLE articulos
(Nombre     VARCHAR(100), 
 precio     INT, 
 fabricante INT
);

CREATE TABLE Fabricante
(Nombre VARCHAR(100), 
 codigo INT
);


INSERT INTO articulos
(Nombre
, precio
, fabricante
 )
VALUES
('camisa1', 100, 1),
('camisa2', 111, 1),
('camisa3', 110, 1),
('camisa4', 111, 1),
('camisa5', 100, 2),
('camisa6', 100, 1);

INSERT INTO Fabricante
 (Nombre, codigo)
VALUES
('pepe', 1),
('juan', 2);

SELECT A.Nombre
 , A.Fabricante
 , A.Precio
 , F.Nombre
FROM 
 ARTICULOS A
 INNER JOIN FABRICANTE F ON F.Codigo = A.Fabricante
                            AND A.Precio =
(
   SELECT MAX(A.Precio)
    FROM 
     ARTICULOS A
       WHERE A.Fabricante = F.Codigo
);
```

El resultado de la query es que tienes todos los artículos cuyo precio sea igual al mayor por fabricante.

Además si observas el plan de ejecución, realmente los motores no van leyendo fila por fila y buscando si el valor encaja con el máximo. Lo que hacen es ejecutar por una lado el conjunto "padre", y por otro lado el conjunto de la subquery, y luego realizan un join para mezclar los resultados, obteniendo así un rendimiento bueno.

[image: Resultado query]

Answer (score 0):

**La subconsulta**

- Buscará obtener el precio máximo de la tabla artículos
- Lo anterior siempre y cuando *donde* el fabricante de la tabla artículos sea igual al código de la tabla fabricantes

La subconsulta anterior devolverá una sola fila considerando que se esta usando una función de agregación.

Luego entonces.

El resultado que te haya devuelto la operación anterior se buscará igualar con la columna precio de la tabla artículos.

Recordando que tenemos un `INNER JOIN` este buscará devolvernos únicamente filas de la tabla izquierda que tengan un registro asociado con la tabla de la derecha ignorando a los demás.

Entonces:

Si revisamos tu consulta vamos a obtener 4 columnas en total relacionando a la tabla articulos y la tabla fabricantes a través de la columna código de fabricante que referencia de la tabla artículos a la tabla fabricantes, (hasta aquí pudieramos estar obteniendo múltiples registros ya que pudieran existir registros variados cumpliendo esta condición).

Sin embargo tenemos en nuestra consulta un segundo *filtro* por así decirlo que nos dice:

> No solo debe existir relación entre las tablas mencionadas a través del código del fabricante sino que además se debe cumplir que el precio de la tabla artículos sea igual al máximo precio registrado **Siempre que el código del fabricante exista en la tabla fabricantes**

Punto a mencionar.

Esta consulta al tener dentro una función de agregación solo estaría regresando un renglón ignorando a todos los demás fabricantes con su precio mayor, entonces *considero* haría falta considero que se agrupe dentro de la sub consulta para mostrar todos los registros máximos y así obtengas mas de un renglón.

Dentro de tu subconsulta debería verse así:

```
.......(SELECT ARTICULOS.id, MAX(A.Precio) FROM ARTICULOS A 
WHERE A.Fabricante = F.Codigo GROUP BY ARTICULOS.id)...
```

Answer (score -1):

Observación:

> ¿Compara cada campo de `Artículos.Fabricante` con cada campo de `Fabricantes.Codigo`? o ¿Cómo funciona este último **`WHERE`**?

```
A.Precio=(
    SELECT MAX(A.Precio) FROM ARTICULOS A
    WHERE A.Fabricante = F.Codigo
)
```

Siempre agarra el método del cangrejo.

Lo que hace la consulta es que va a buscar los datos que son iguales `WHERE A.Fabricante = F.Codigo`. Una vez encontrados esos datos iguales de la tabla `ARTICULOS` va a dar el `precio max` de los datos que tienen igualdad.